# making two anchor tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I am looking to add two anchor links when the mouse enters `#intro`and hide intro and when the mouse leaves the original intro shows.

```js
$("#intro").on("mouseenter", function() {
  var link = $("<a>");
  var link2 = $("<a>");

  link.attr("href", "en.html");
  link2.attr("href", "fr.html");

  link.text("Welcome!");
  link2.text("Bienvenue!");

  $("#intro").addClass("link link2");
  $("#intro").html(link && link2);
});

$("#intro").on("mouseleave", function() {
  show(slow, this)
});
```

Comment: Do you want to toggle **create/remove** anchor tags on `onmouseover` event? or just **show/hide** the tag?

Comment: both would work I guess! I tried with toggle but because I am adding a new function when mouse is over the id, I didn't get the result I am looking for.

Comment: `.html(link && link2)` is definitely not doing what you are expecting

Comment: yeah, that's why i am asking here!

Comment: One thing to note is check your browser dev tools console for errors and include those messages in question. Your function call for `show()` is a function not definied and is incorrect if it is for jQuery.show()

Comment: So for starters why do you need to insert those elements only when mouse enters and not just have them there to start with and use some `:hover` css to display them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#intro").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("link link2");
    $("#intro a").show();
    $("#intro h1").hide();
  });
  
  $("#intro").mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("link link2");
    $("#intro a").hide();
    $("#intro h1").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#intro {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#intro a{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
  <h1>Intro</h1>
  <a href='en.html'>Welcome!</a>
  <a href='fr.html'>Bienvenue!</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#intro {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#intro a,
#intro:hover h1{
  display:none;
}

#intro:hover a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
  <h1>Intro</h1>
  <a href='en.html'>Welcome!</a>
  <a href='fr.html'>Bienvenue!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The hide/show could be done much cleaner with `:hover` css and no need for js. In fact no need for js to do any of this

Comment: I am gonna try that!

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working, i added display:block; to .intro and  .intro:hover{
       display:none;
   } this hides the first class, but the problem is with showing the other anchors; so i added display:none; to other two anchors and  .link:hover{
       display:block;
   } but it doesn't work!